# Connect API - set ContentVersion custom field on file upload

Tags: files, contentversion, connect-api

I'm trying to upload a file with the following [request](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/intro_input.htm#fileDataExample):

```
curl -H "X-PrettyPrint: 1" -F 'json={"title":"BoatPrices"};type=application/json' 
-F "fileData=@BoatPrices.pdf;type=application/octet-stream" 
-X POST https://instance_name/services/data/v53.0/connect/files/users/me 
-H 'Authorization: OAuth 00DRR0000000N0g!...' --insecure
```

It works fine, the title is set on `ContentVersion`. However, when I try to add a custom field value, next to title, I get an exception: `Unrecognized field \"Custom__c\" at [line:1, column:41]`. Is there a way to set a custom field value in a single request?